# Are BIGNUM BN_ functions deprecated in openssl 1.1?

Tags: c, linux, openssl

I was compiling some 'C' code that uses openssl under Fedora 27 (version 1.1.0g-1). I made some needed changes (from the 1.0.2 version of my code) and things now compile o.k. again.

I then tried to compile with the option "OPENSSL_API_COMPAT=0x10100000L" which I understand causes the compiler to not include APIs deprecated in openssl version 1.1.

Now, my code won't compile and seems to not find the definitions of things like BN_bin2bn() and BN_free().

Looking at the headers, /usr/include/openssl/dh.h doesn't even include bn.h at all with this option set.

So, are the BN_xxxx functions now all deprecated in 1.1?

Looking at the openssl 1.1 documents in places like https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_1.1.0_Changes doesn't mention this being the case.

The description of BN_bin2bn() at https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/crypto/BN_bin2bn.html doesn't indicate this as deprecated as far as I can see.

Am I missing something? If these functions are deprecated, I would like to know what I'm supposed to use instead (for dh.h things, etc.).

Thanks;

.....c:927:8: error: implicit declaration of function ‘BN_bin2bn’; did you mean ‘OBJ_nid2sn’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]

p = BN_bin2bn(dh1024_p, sizeof dh1024_p, NULL);
        ^~~~~~~~~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BN functions are still present and non-deprecated.  Check out the lack of relevant `#if`s preceding line 180 in https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0-stable/include/openssl/bn.h

Looks like they must've just done some header-refactoring to eliminate header coupling.  In fact, in the dh header for 1.1 we now see

```
# if OPENSSL_API_COMPAT < 0x10100000L
#  include <openssl/bn.h>
# endif
```

at line 20 in https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_1_0-stable/include/openssl/dh.h.  So moving forward they don't include the bignum header automatically.  This sounds exactly like improving the header coupling.

Try explicitly adding `#include <openssl/bn.h>` after your include of dh.h.

Comment: I explicitly adding dh.h and bn.h and it compiles o.k. now with OPENSSL_API_COMPAT=0x10100000L. My goal is to update any outdated stuff while I'm in the neighborhood.